# How to select faces while using texture painting in 2.8?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm texture painting an axe, and there's a certain part of the axe that I want to select.

[image: I only want to select that]

I only want to select that whole black sharp part, but I can't select anything while texture painting. I'm using Blender 2.8.

How can I select while using texture painting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you have this issue on Blender 2.8 because you're using the default Left click select keymap?

First things first:

In order to enable the face selection masking, push down that little button in the viewport header:

[image: face mask button's picture]

Then, in order to select the faces you want to paint on, use the <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>. You can also access some selection tools, like Border Select with <kbd>B</kbd>, or Circle Select with <kbd>C</kbd>.

For more advanced control of selection, you can switch to edit mode, do what you need and switch back to paint mode.