# Vertex paint not working after sculpting with dyntopo on

Tags: vertex-paint, sculpt

I started painted a low poly island model some weeks ago.  Today I modified the mesh with sculpt mode and when I activated Dyntopo, I got this warning:

[image]

Then I tried to vertex paint the new vertices but it is not working, the new vertices don't get painted. Here you can see my settings:

[image]

What I am doing wrong or missing to do? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Dyntopo sculpting mode removes all data related to mesh since it regenerates it, vertex paint included. It won't prevent from vertex painting though rather only remove previously existing one. As to painting see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126566/1245, looks like you have masking turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender is a complex application. I don't know exactly what I did, but at the point when I wrote my question, for some reason I had changed the Draw mode to Add instead of Mix. Once I put it back to Mix, it worked as expected and I was able to keep working in this project.
[image]